# How to install Python docx module on mac osx

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to generate `.docx` files using Python. I searched the web and posts here and found a module:

https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/README.markdown

It says to install using `easy_install` or `pip`, which I have no idea how to do. I went to python website to install pip from the instructions given on python documentation:

http://guide.python-distribute.org/installation.html

So I downloaded and followed directions:

```
$ tar xzf pip-0.7.2.tar.gz
$ cd pip-0.7.2
$ python setup.py install
```

But when I do python setup.py install, I get error message:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:pip-0.7.2 John$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
from setuptools import setup

ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Can someone please help me install step by step for a newb? Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Just install `pip` and it should be easy from there. Google for a tutorial.

Comment: yeah tried that... no success.  hence me posting.....

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What didn't work?

Comment: have you tried downloading the source and running `python setup.py install` in the directory where you downloaded it?

Comment: I updated post.  When I try to install pip, it says no module named setuptools.  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip can install straight from the git repository

You just have to tell him to use git and give him the URL of the git rep

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx.git
```

You will also need to install lxml (as written in the setup.py) and PIL (as you will discover when you try to import the module).

```
pip install PIL
pip install lxml
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Thanks... but can you please instruct me how to install pip for mac os x?  as you can see above I am having problems when I even follow the directions on python website.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I installed pip, PIL, lxml, but when I run file, I get this error now:  


$ python test_docx.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_docx.py", line 7, in <module>
    from docx import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from core import Docx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser
ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser

Comment: This seems to be another extension you need to install. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/

$pip install python-dateutil

Comment: Though I would make sure to use the version of pip you have on your Mac e.g.: `pip3 install ...`