# how i can print my key, value dictionary or either list get extracted in word?

Tags: python

I have data collection of lists. I want the value to get extracted in word file.

```
item = {"Maling":["melon jam 300gram", "34aed"], "nescafe":["3 in 1 coffee", "20 aed"]}
```

I want this key and value data automatically get written in word file as shown below.

```
Maling
Melon jam 400
34 aed
```

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: A couple of things to either correct in your question and/or note. 1) You didn't state you wanted units (grams, currency) removed but it's in your expected output. 2) Related, spacing 3) Somehow, you're going from a 300gram jar to a 400 {which is probably a simple typo)

Comment: i dont want anything get removed . they key is a brand and value is item description and price so i want the key and value get formatted into the world file so that i can print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import docx
mydoc = docx.Document()

item = {"Maling":["melon jam 300gram", "34aed"], "nescafe":["3 in 1 coffee", "20 aed"]}

for i in item:
    mydoc.add_paragraph(i)
    for j in item[i]:
        mydoc.add_paragraph(j)

mydoc.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/pythonProject10/docx/price.py", line 2, in <module>
    mydoc = docx.Document()
AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'

Comment: Please install: `pip install python-docx`

Comment: i install pip3 install python-docx

Comment: mydoc = docx.Document()
AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'

Comment: You can try this:`https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html`

Comment: brother i am working in mac not windows so is there other way to fix.

Comment: one more try: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998465/how-to-install-python-docx-module-on-mac-osx`

Comment: you want to me run this one in terminal of pycharm right